# What's the difference between a public static class member function and a global function declared in a namespace?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between these two declarations?

```
class foo
{
public:
    static void bar();
};
```

and

```
namespace foo
{
    void bar();
}
```

The way I see it, there is none, since `bar` in `class foo` doesn't have access to `this`, and neither does `bar` in namespace `foo`.

This is purely theoretical, of course.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but I would say that the main difference is that you can create instances of class foo, but not of the namespace. (Of course creating instances of a class that only has one static member is rather useless...) EDIT: Oh, and you might also inherit from class foo, in that case it might even make sense to have an almost empty class like that.

Comment: @ValarDohaeris: You can prevent this to a certain extent by making the destructor or constructor private.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Namespace + functions versus static methods on a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434937/namespace-functions-versus-static-methods-on-a-class)

Comment: Also, check this link for a list of some differences: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3188198/908336 (The most important one is that you can reopen a namespace and add stuff across translation units, which is impossible with classes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the difference between a public static class member function and a global function declared in a namespace?

- The class member function will be able to access private static member of the class, while a function inside a namespace will not directly have any kind of data protection
- As pointed out by [@ValarDohaeris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1805388/valardohaeris), you can create an object of class `foo` and call `obj.bar()` even in an object context, while the same cannot be achieved with namespaces as there are no instances of namespaces
- The namespace can be *imported* via `using` making `bar()` a valid call
- As mentioned by [@John5342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365460/john5342) you can use the class `foo` at template argument. For example in `template<typename T> fun() { T::bar(); }`

Comment: C++ has no `self`, it's called `this`

Comment: I better stop mixing Ruby coding and C++ answering.

Comment: You could add that `template<typename T_> fun() {T_::bar();}` can be called with the class version but not the namespace.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: even though not applicable in this context (no argument), you forgot about ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup): it only applies to functions within namespaces.

Answer (score 7):

Functions defined at namespace scope can be found via [argument dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup):

```
namespace foo
{
    class bar;
    void baz (bar);
}

foo::bar x;
baz (x); // Ok, baz is found by ADL
```

If foo is a class instead of a namespace, this does not work.

Comment: +1. Not the only difference but certainly an important one that is not mentioned in the answer accepted by the author of this question.