# What is the main difference between namespace & class?

Tags: c++

Why I should using the `namespace` instead the `class`? Where is the main difference? For example, in JavaScript the `namespace` can  be emulated by classes. So, what the point to create namespace instead class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between classes and namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188156/difference-between-classes-and-namespaces)

Comment: You can't create instances of a `namespace`; you can create instances of a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an analogous question: What is the main difference between an office chair and a train? You can emulate an office chair by sitting on a train. What is the point of using an office chair instead of a train?

Classes are a types. It is possible to instantiate objects of types. For example:

```
class foo{}; // a class
foo f;       // this variable is instance of the class
```

Namespaces are not types. It is not possible to create instances of namespaces.

---

Furthermore, it is possible to have template classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct bar{};
```

It is not possible to have namespace templates.

---

On the other hand, it is possible to have anonymous namespaces, and it is possible to bring members of a namespace into another namespace with `using` declaration, which is not possible with members of a class.

---

> So, what the point to create namespace instead class?

We need to group names into smaller scopes to avoid name collisions. That is what namespaces are for.

Classes have a scope as well sure, but when we don't need a type, there is no point in defining a class.

Answer (score 3):

A `namespace` is just a way to separate and group identifiers to avoid naming conflicts at compile-time.  A `class` is an actual type that you can allocate memory for and create instances of.